# Is there any difference between "wipe" and "wipe down"?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between *wipe* and *wipe down*? For example:

> I am going to **wipe** the board, so write down what I have written.
>
> I am going to **wipe down** the board, so write down what I have written.

And by the way, do I have to use *what* or *that* in the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of *down* implies a physical activity, while omitting it implies a result or activity that's somewhat removed from the physical (deleting something).

> ✔ I am going to *wipe* the computer's memory.
>   ✘ I am going to *wipe down* the computer's memory.

In this example, it doesn't make any sense to use *wipe down* with computer memory, because that's not something that can be physically touched.

> ✘ I am going to *wipe* the car.
>   ✔ I am going to *wipe down* the car.

Here, I would have no idea what *wiping* a car is—because you can't delete cars. On the other hand, *wiping down* a car generally means applying a cloth to remove dirt or water.

(Note that we often omit prepositions in speech. if somebody actually said ***wipe*** *the car*, I would understand from context that they meant ***wipe down*** *the car*. As such, the expression without *down* is not actually wrong in regular discourse—but it wouldn't be quite as natural, and I'm trying to show the literal difference between the two.)

---

To be more specific, compare the following situations.

Sitting at a computer keyboard and typing commands:

> ✔ I am going to *wipe* the motherboard.
>   ✘ I am going to *wipe down* the motherboard.

Holding a motherboard and cloth in your hand:

> ✘ I am going to *wipe* the motherboard.
>   ✔ I am going to *wipe down* the motherboard.

---

The object in the question appears to be a blackboard, on which there is writing.  This is a particular instance where the two different senses of *wipe* can be applied to the same thing.

It can accept *wipe* in the sense of *removing information*. It can also accept *wipe down* in the sense of *cleaning*.

> ✔ I am going to ***wipe*** the board, so write down what I have written.
>   → I am going to *remove (delete) the information* from the blackboard.
>
> ✔ I am going to ***wipe down*** the board, so write down what I have written.
>   → I am going to *clean the chalk* off of the whiteboard.

---

So, both are fine. Which you use is based on the specific sense you are trying to convey. Are you talking about the information represented by the blackboard or are you talking about the physical chalk marks? (Note that the final result is mostly the same, with the one sense impacting the other.)